# What does AWS access key mean in the context of a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

When I setup a user in AWS IAM, I get the option to specify a User name and enable both programmatic and console access. After I select both these options, go ahead and create the user (lets assume xyz is the User name), I get 3 messages below.

Created user xyz 
**Created access key for user xyz** 
Created login profile for user xyz

Now, I understand access key exists separately from a user and these are provided in CLI without any reference or linking to the User name. The second message i.e. **Created access key for user xyz** seems a bit confusing - Why does AWS link User name with Access keys? Are they not independent? 
 My question is - You access console by one set of credentials which is User name and Password and for CLI access, you provide a completely different set of credentials which is Access key id and Secret access key.
In which way is the User name related to the access key - The message shown by AWS after successful creation of User indicates that there is some sort of binding or relation between a User name and access key - Need some clarity around this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The access key is tied to the user - with the access key and secret, you are authenticating as the user. You can only have 2 access keys attached to a user

"Access keys are long-term credentials for an IAM user or the AWS account root user. You can use access keys to sign programmatic requests to the AWS CLI or AWS API"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html

Comment: Thank you Jorg - I think I understood the concept now, the user is the Principal and it has 2 independent set of credentials - the username password and access key id secret key. A policy that is applied to the Principal will determine the Authorization irrespective of how they Authenticate i.e. through Username or through Access Keys.

Comment: Abhishek Palakkal Kaliyath - correct, irrespective of authentication method, the same roles/policies will apply